# OnClickListener for button not working using Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, button

i have a problem with button clicking using setOnClickListener

The problem is the following. I have a menu consisting of three fragments. From one fragment, you need to switch to the Data Entry Layout. A button is used for the transition. But logically it doesn't work. I don't understand why. Help please.

1. Controller to button

```
package com.example.client_ismpr_system

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.client_ismpr_system.adapters.equipment.EquipmentAdapter
import com.example.client_ismpr_system.models.Equipment

class MakingNewEquipmentFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val navButton: Button? = view?.findViewById(R.id.nav_button_to_new_order)
    navButton?.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println("Test")
        }
    })
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_making_new_equipment, container, false)

    val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)

    val equipmentsList = listOf(
        Equipment(data), Equipment(data),  Equipment(data), Equipment(data),
    )

    val adapter = EquipmentAdapter(requireContext(), equipmentsList)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    return view
}

}
```

2. Button in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/main_theme_color"
tools:context=".MakingNewEquipmentFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nav_button_to_new_order"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
    android:text="@string/text_making_new_order" />

</LinearLayout>
```

A Setonclicklistener handler has been created here, but it doesn't work. Also, on the advice of other participants, my View returns. but none of this works. The button just doesn't work. Logs are not output to LogCat.
I am expecting that the button will me workable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [Fragment lifecycle documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle#states), `onCreate` runs **before** `onCreateView`, so your `view` is always going to be null there.

If you want to ensure your view exists, you should use `onViewCreated`, which is passed the View that `onCreateView` returns.

By using the Fragment constructor that takes a `R.layout` ID, you don't actually need to override `onCreateView` at all, so your Fragment should look like:

```
class MakingNewEquipmentFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_making_new_equipment) {

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)

        val equipmentsList = listOf(
            Equipment(data), Equipment(data),  Equipment(data), Equipment(data),
        )

        val adapter = EquipmentAdapter(requireContext(), equipmentsList)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

        val navButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.nav_button_to_new_order)
        navButton.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println("Test")
        }
    }
}
```